# Non blocking failed step in AWS Codepipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

I am wondering if I can use the AWS Codepipeline to have a step that I can skip over even if it fails. Eventually I want it to be blocking. But for now, ideally it can notify the user with a red cell that it failed.

Another option that could work is to have this step run in parallel while the remaining (and subsequent steps) run unaffected by the outcome of this step.

But I couldn't find any way to get this working for me.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: As per the below comment from @futchas, this is now supported by AWS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/reference-pipeline-structure.html

---

Checked with AWS Support and they say that this is unsupported currently. They may add a feature in the future.

Comment: Parallel codepipelines have been added. Just define multiple action-blocks inside a stage. Check this doc and the runOrder attribute: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/reference-pipeline-structure.html